# JAVA Assignment & Operators

Tags: java, arrays, oop, operators, assignment-operator

the code below is printing out **15 15**, however I was expecting it to print out **12 15**. It seems like the fix method is updating a1 so that it contains 3,7,5 as opposed to 3,4,5. Anyone know why this is the case?

```
class PassA 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    PassA p = new PassA();
    p.start();
}

void start() 
{
    long [] a1 = {3,4,5};
    long [] a2 = fix(a1);
    System.out.print(a1[0] + a1[1] + a1[2] + " ");
    System.out.println(a2[0] + a2[1] + a2[2]);
}

long [] fix(long [] a3) 
{
    a3[1] = 7;
    return a3;
}
}
```

Comment: What would you have happen instead? In the end a2 and a1 point to the same array, which you have modified to have 7 as the middle element.

Comment: As far as you're not performing deep copy of array in the `fix` method, `a1` and `a2` are both referencing array with values `{3,4,5}`.

Comment: fix() gets as an argument a reference to an array. This means that it change the values of the original array.

fix() changes the value of the second cell (remember that array indexes starts from 0) making it {3,7,5}

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following

```
 long[] fix(long[] a3) { // a3=a1 and a1= {3,4,5}
    a3[1] = 7; // a3[1]=7 means a1[1] will become 7(a1[1]=7), now a1={3,7,5}
    return a3;// return a1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would achieve your target 12 15

```
long [] fix(long [] a3) 
{
    return new long[]{a3[0], 7, a3[2]};
}
```

Because otherwise, you pass a1 (named as a3), modify an element, which subsequently changes it in a1. So now a1 is changed. Later on you return a1 and set it to a2.. So a2 and a1 are pointing to the same array {3,7,5}

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the array by reference, thats why in the `fix()` method, the original array gets modified. You can pass a copy to the method using

```
long [] a2 = fix( Arrays.copyOf(a1, a1.length));.
```

*OK, technically, you are passing the array by value, but the value **is** the reference.*

Comment: You might wanna check this thread, since java is allways pass by value ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Because in Java arrays are object, when passing by value you pass the reference.

Comment: Ok if wouldn't pass arrays, instead I'd pass a fixed value i.e string or integer, how would this differ?

Comment: Everything in Java gets passed by value, which means that the parameter gets **copied** when entering a method. When passing primitives (byte, short, int, long, float, double, boolean, char) they simply get copied, you have a new primitive inside the method that has the same value as the one passed as a parameter. When passing **anything** else, you are passing an object reference, which in turn gets copied when entering the method. But you are still operating on the original object. This is also why the original array gets modified.